# According to the Rambam, if I make a vow and I realize that it was based on an error, is it still binding?

Tags: halacha, rambam, nedarim-shevuot

If, for example, I say that I won't eat tomatoes but my intention was to make a [neder](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neder) about "not eating red vegetables" (this is why I said tomato). A year after, I realize that a tomato is a fruit and not a vegetable. Is my neder still binding?

Comment: FYI - some tomatoes are yellow or green. Perhaps, this fact, may still bind your vow.

Comment: −1 for specifying _Rambam_ without any explanation of why you'd want to restrict to his view.

Comment: Note tomatoes are fruits and vegetables, bc they are fruits and 'vegetable' isn't a well-defined category.

Comment: Why Rambam? Do you want a talmidei harambam debate? And the fruit thing is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

It's a Mishna in Nedarim states that vows based on an error are one of 4 types of vows that are invalid.

> פרק ג - משנה א
>
> אַרְבָּעָה נְדָרִים הִתִּירוּ חֲכָמִים, נִדְרֵי זֵרוּזִין, וְנִדְרֵי הֲבַאי, וְ**נִדְרֵי שְׁגָגוֹת**, וְנִדְרֵי אֳנָסִים
>
> End of פרק ג - משנה ב
>
> **נִדְרֵי שְׁגָגוֹת**, אִם אָכָלְתִּי וְאִם שָׁתִיתִי, וְנִזְכַּר שֶׁאָכַל וְשָׁתָה. שֶׁאֲנִי אוֹכֵל וְשֶׁאֲנִי שׁוֹתֶה, וְשָׁכַח וְאָכַל וְשָׁתָה. אָמַר, קוֹנָם אִשְׁתִּי נֶהֱנֵית  לִי, שֶׁגָּנְבָה אֶת כִּיסִי וְשֶׁהִכְּתָה אֶת בְּנִי, וְנוֹדַע שֶׁלֹּא הִכַּתּוּ וְנוֹדַע שֶׁלֹּא גְנָבָתּוּ

Seems the Rambam in [הלכות נדרים - פרק שמינ](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02021.html#HtmpReportNum0019_L2)י paskens the same way:

> **ג** אֲבָל הַנּוֹדֵר אוֹ הַנִּשְׁבָּע שֶׁאֵינִי נוֹשֵׂא פְּלוֹנִית הַכְּעוּרָה וְנִמְצֵאת נָאָה. שְׁחוֹרָה וְנִמְצֵאת לְבָנָה. קְצָרָה וְנִמְצֵאת אֲרֻכָּה. קוֹנָם שֶׁאֵין אִשְׁתִּי נֶהֱנֵית לִי שֶׁגָּנְבָה אֶת כִּיסִי וְשֶׁהִכְּתָה אֶת בְּנִי וְנוֹדַע שֶׁלֹּא גָּנְבָה וְשֶׁלֹּא הִכְּתָה. הֲרֵי זֶה מֻתָּר מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהוּא **נֵדֶר טָעוּת וְהוּא בִּכְלַל נִדְרֵי שְׁגָגוֹת שֶׁהֵן מֻתָּרִין**. וְאֵין זֶה כְּתוֹלֶה נִדְרוֹ בְּדָבָר וְלֹא נִתְקַיֵּם הַדָּבָר. שֶׁהֲרֵי הַסִּבָּה שֶׁבִּגְלָלָהּ נָדַר לֹא הָיְתָה מְצוּיָה וְטָעוּת הָיָה ‏